# Waiting for na75.salesforce.com

Tags: data-import-wizard

I am trying to use the data import wizard today & the screen remains blank.  In bottom left corner, there is a message "waiting for na75.salesforce.com."  Trust Status page doesn't have any issues listed related to this.  Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: I just tested an org that I apparently have on na75, it's working fine. Try clearing your cache, restarting your browser, and/or restarting your device. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved on its own after 30 minutes.